# How to wait for all event handlers in backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to perform some action, when all event handlers for some event are done.

My idea was to pass an object in event:

```
self.trigger("my_event", {handlers: x, callback: function});
```

And in the handlers I'd write something like:

```
handler = function(lock){
  lock.handlers --;
  if (lock.handlers == 0){
    lock.callback();
  }
}
```

(obviously that'd be the lock object's responsibility, but you can see the idea)

But I don't know how to get information about number of handlers (`x` in my example) registered for the event. Is this possible? Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: If you are also using jQuery, then you could use the features of the Deferred object: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ & http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/, specifically the `jQuery.when()` function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the registered handlers are all called by the "trigger" function itself; so when that call returns, each of the handlers have also.  Consider this example:

```javascript
function checkTriggers() {
  var o = {};
  _.extend(o, Backbone.Events);
  o.on('foo', function(){console.log('ONE');});
  o.on('foo', function(){console.log('TWO');});
  o.trigger('foo');
  console.log('THREE');
}
```

The log sequence will always be ONE, TWO, THREE.  So it seems like you can simply perform your action after the call to "trigger".  However, if any callback functions use a delay (e.g. with "setTimeout") then you've got a different problem.